# Suggestions For Syncing Audio With Audio Queue Services?

Tags: cocoa, macos, audio, core-audio

I'm decoding a video format that has an accompanying audio track in a separate file. Per the specs, I render a frame of video every 1/75th second. And the length of the video file is the same as the length of the audio track.

I'm playing the audio with Audio Queue Services (which I chose because I figured there would be situations where I needed precise timing control -- just the sort of situation I'm encountering!). It's a big API and I haven't progressed much past the sample code in Apple's programming guide (though I have wrapped things up in a nicer ObjC API).

In ideal situations, things work fine with the basic playback setup. The video and audio stays synced and both end at the same time (within my own ability to tell the difference). However, if performance hiccups (or I attach the Leaks Instrument or something), they quickly get out of sync.

This is the first time I've ever written something of this nature: I have no prior experience with sound or video. I certainly have no experience with Audio Queue Services. So I'm not sure where to go from here.

Have you done something like this? Do you have some advice or tips or tricks to offer? Is there some fundamental piece of documentation I need to read? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to play the video?

Comment: I've created a CGContextRef with CGBitmapContextCreate and am writing pixels to its data-stream and turning that into a CGImageRef for drawing into a CALayer. For efficiency's sake, I only update the pixels that change every frame. Fortunately, it's a very low-quality video format.

Comment: @JamesWilliams I am developing similar kind of application,rendering video and sending audio data separately trying to sync using Audio Queue Services, achieved the result too, but it gave glitches in sound,used AudioQueueReset for syncing sound with video but getting glitches, if u share snippet of programming to play audio will be very appriciable ...or any thought over this will be helpfull

Comment: @PRSingh Sorry, I gave up on this over 7 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I've never actually coded anything like this so I'm shooting from the hip.  Also, I've done a decent amount of programming with the HAL and AUHAL but never with AudioQueue so my approach might not be the best way to use AQ.

Obviously the first thing to decide is whether to sync the audio to the video or the video to the audio.  From the question it seems you've decided the video will be the master and the audio should sync to it.

I would approach this by keeping track of the number of frames of video rendered, along with the frame rate.  Then, when enqueuing your audio buffers, rather than passing a monotonically increasing value for the startTime adjust the buffer's start time to match any discontinuities observed in the video.  This is a bit vague because I don't know exactly where your audio is coming from or how you are enqueuing it, but hopefully the principle is clear.

Comment: I picked AudioQueue because it seemed pretty low level. But maybe it's not low-level enough. Would you recommend jumping in deeper to HAL and AUHAL? Do you know where the documentation for that would be? / As for offsetting the buffers, that could be a tough one since I don't really know what I'm doing and the AudioQueue functions does a lot of that for you. / But it's probably the only answer. Maybe a jump to lower level really would help.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the HAL directly unless you have to.  As far as documentation goes- most of it is in the header files, but it is sparse at best.  AUHAL isn't too bad if you're familiar with Audio Units.  In either case, the learning curve is steep!

Comment: I found some resources for seeking in an Audio Buffer. So I think I should be able to adapt the answer you have for that. But, if not, I'll have to study up on Audio Units. Either way, I think this is the best answer I'm likely to get on SO for such an esoteric question. Thanks for the help!